# Oracle data pump export performance query

Tags: database, oracle

I need to export two schemas in my Oracle 11.2.0.4 database that totals 500GB in size. My problem is the duration of the export. It was still running 14 hours later before crashing out because of disk space. This is a standard edition database so I don't have the option to invoke the parallel parameter. I'm not an Oracle guru and would really appreciate some tips on how to speed this up. It seems to be taking a huge amount of time with the stats. Can I exclude them and regenerate them after I import. Please find some database parameter values below:

SGA Target: 6G
PGA_aggregate_target: 3G
db_cache_size: 0
stream_pool_size: 0
NOARCHVIVEMODE: enabled

Thanks

Comment: [`EXCLUDE=STATISTICS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL847), and see [performance section](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_perf.htm) (or [19c version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-data-pump-performance-tips.html)). But your real issue seems to be disk space?

Comment: Thanks Alex. Is there any negatives to excluding the stats from export?

Comment: They would have to be regenerated after import. Can't think of anything else.

Comment: what is the value of  `job_queue_processes` ?

Comment: Hi Roberto - value set to 1000